# Bash - use loop to make backup script more efficient

Tags: bash

I've a backup script (bash). Part of it is shown below. This script does a 14 day rotation of the backup. If I want to change this to say 30 days, I'd have to write out 30 such if-then blocks. I'm sure this could be replaced by a nifty for-loop. What would it be?

```
# step 1: delete the oldest snapshot, if it exists:
if [ -d $BACKUP_DIR/daily.14 ] ; then                   \
$RM -rf $BACKUP_DIR/daily.14 ;                          \
fi ;

# step 2: shift the middle snapshot(s) back by one, if they exist
if [ -d $BACKUP_DIR/daily.13 ] ; then                   \
$MV $BACKUP_DIR/daily.13 $BACKUP_DIR/daily.14 ; \
fi;

if [ -d $BACKUP_DIR/daily.12 ] ; then                   \
$MV $BACKUP_DIR/daily.12 $BACKUP_DIR/daily.13 ; \
fi;

if [ -d $BACKUP_DIR/daily.11 ] ; then                   \
$MV $BACKUP_DIR/daily.11 $BACKUP_DIR/daily.12 ; \
fi;

if [ -d $BACKUP_DIR/daily.10 ] ; then                   \
$MV $BACKUP_DIR/daily.10 $BACKUP_DIR/daily.11 ; \
fi;

if [ -d $BACKUP_DIR/daily.9 ] ; then                    \
$MV $BACKUP_DIR/daily.9 $BACKUP_DIR/daily.10 ;  \
fi;

if [ -d $BACKUP_DIR/daily.8 ] ; then                    \
$MV $BACKUP_DIR/daily.8 $BACKUP_DIR/daily.9 ;   \
fi;

if [ -d $BACKUP_DIR/daily.7 ] ; then                    \
$MV $BACKUP_DIR/daily.7 $BACKUP_DIR/daily.8 ;   \
fi;

if [ -d $BACKUP_DIR/daily.6 ] ; then                    \
$MV $BACKUP_DIR/daily.6 $BACKUP_DIR/daily.7 ;   \
fi;

if [ -d $BACKUP_DIR/daily.5 ] ; then                    \
$MV $BACKUP_DIR/daily.5 $BACKUP_DIR/daily.6 ;   \
fi;

if [ -d $BACKUP_DIR/daily.4 ] ; then                    \
$MV $BACKUP_DIR/daily.4 $BACKUP_DIR/daily.5 ;   \
fi;

if [ -d $BACKUP_DIR/daily.3 ] ; then                    \
$MV $BACKUP_DIR/daily.3 $BACKUP_DIR/daily.4 ;   \
fi;

if [ -d $BACKUP_DIR/daily.2 ] ; then                    \
$MV $BACKUP_DIR/daily.2 $BACKUP_DIR/daily.3 ;   \
fi;

if [ -d $BACKUP_DIR/daily.1 ] ; then                    \
$MV $BACKUP_DIR/daily.1 $BACKUP_DIR/daily.2 ;   \
fi;


# step 3: make a hard-link-only (except for dirs) copy of the latest snapshot, if that exists
if [ -d $BACKUP_DIR/daily.0 ] ; then                    \
$CP -al $BACKUP_DIR/daily.0 $BACKUP_DIR/daily.1 ;       \
fi;
```

Comment: Please try searching on Google atleast once before posting here. There are hundreds of websites that show you how to get this done.

Comment: Perhaps, but I'm new to bash and a Google search for 'bash loop' doesn't produce anything (perhaps it does, but since I'm not all that familiar with bash, I may have missed it or not gotten a hang of it) that applies to this particular case. Thanks though!

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
MAX=29

for i in `seq 1 $MAX` 
do 
    echo " check file exists directory.$i"
    echo "mv directory.$i to directory" `expr $i - 1`
done
```

This might be a good starting point

Comment: Thank you Goblin for pointing me in the right direction. After a fair bit of trail and error, I was able to get it done. Your seq cmd only increments. I needed a decreasing number sequence. I've posted my solution. Thank you again.

Comment: sequence command can also be used for decrement. You can use 
    `seq $MAX -1 1`

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in {7..1};
do
        #echo "$i"

        if [ -d $BACKUP_DIR/daily.${i} ]
        then
                z=$(($i+1));
                #echo "$z"
                echo "moving daily.$i to daily.$z"
                $MV $BACKUP_DIR/daily.$i $BACKUP_DIR/daily.$z ;
        fi;
done
```